# How To Hide A Table Column, But Still Use It With A Click Event? (JQuery Datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm getting a RecordID and a Title from my datasource.  I only want to display the Title column on screen, but I need the RecordID from the row to be used in a click event.  So I'm pulling them both into my table and I'm looking to hide the RecordID.

I have a table that is populated with an ajax source so the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags for my data are dynamically created.  They aren't part of the code, so I can't simply add a class that I can hide with CSS.

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>RecordID</th>
            <th>TITLE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!---Data and tags are dynamically generated--->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The DataTables documentation lists a couple options of adding the function `oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, false )` or the `"bVisible":false` attribute.  Both of these work fine to hide my column, but then the click event I had based on that column will no longer work.

Here's the click event I'm using.

```
$('#example').on('dblclick', 'tr', function(event) {
 var td = $('td', this);
 var RecordID= $(td[0]).text();
});
```

So you can see it's accessing the index of 0 (the first td or column in that row.) Once I hide that column, another td becomes index of 0.
I still need that RecordID column to get information from the row, but I don't want to show it on screen. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need the ID column, why don't you just add the ID as an attribute on the title row.

Comment: If you use datatables fnSetColumnVis method, the column will not available for any javascript operations. Try to hide the column using jquery, by setting the display style.

Comment: If I try this, it only hides the header row.
    `function hideColumn(columnIndex) {$('#example td:nth-child('+(columnIndex+1)+'), #example th:nth-child('+ columnIndex+1)+')').hide();}
hideColumn(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by adding a class when declaring the table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "bFilter":false, 
    "bPaginate":false, 
    "bInfo":false, 
    "bSort":false,
    "bAutoWidth":false,
    "sAjaxSource": "datasource.cfm",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "RecordID", "sClass":"testclass" },
        { "mData": "TITLE" }
    ]
});
 });
```

And then the css

```
.testclass {
display:none;
}
```

The JQuery still works after this.